# LWC related list styling

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, opportunity, html, related-list

I added a title to my related list but a white box is appearing on the grey theme I added. What is the simplest way to solve this issue. Should I not use lightning-card to display my title? Also How can we add an items, sorted by and updated subtitle?(like shown in the second picture)

```html
<template>
    
    <div class="slds-box slds-theme_shade">
        <lightning-card title="Opportunity" icon-name="standard:opportunity"></lightning-card>
            <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters slds-p-bottom_x-small slds-p-left_x-small">
            <lightning-input type="search" onchange={handleSearch}></lightning-input></div></div>
    
        <div class="slds-scrollable" style="height:400px; width: auto" >
             <lightning-datatable
                 data={opportunities} 
                 columns={cols} 
                 key-field="id" 
                 onrowselection={handleRowSelection} 
                 onrowaction={handleRowAction} 
                 show-row-number-column="true" 
                 sorted-by={sortBy}
                 sorted-direction={sortDirection}
                 onsort={handleSortAccountData}
                 hide-checkbox-column="true">
                 
                </lightning-datatable>
        </div>
         
    
 
</template>
```

```
import { LightningElement, api, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import getopportunities from '@salesforce/apex/oppcontrol.getopportunities';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex'


const Columns = [
    {label: 'Opp Name', fieldName: 'link', type: 'url', typeAttributes: {label: {fieldName: 'Name'}}, sortable: "true"},
    {label: 'Account Name', fieldName: 'accountlink', type: 'url', typeAttributes:{label: {fieldName: 'Account_Name'}}, sortable: "true"},
    {label: 'End User',fieldName: 'End_User_link', type: 'url', typeAttributes:{label: {fieldName: 'End_User__c'}}, sortable: "true"},
    {label: 'Amount', fieldName: 'Amount', type: 'currency', sortable: "true"},
    {label: 'Close Date', fieldName: 'CloseDate', sortable: "true"},
    {label: 'Stage Name', fieldName: 'StageName', sortable: "true"},
    {label: 'Market', fieldName: 'Market__c', sortable: "true"},
    {label: 'Industry', fieldName: 'Industry__c', sortable: "true"},
    {label: 'Segment', fieldName: 'Segment__c', sortable: "true"},
    {label: 'Transaction Type', fieldName: 'Transaction_Type__c', sortable: "true"}
    ]

export default class Finalopp extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @api recordId;
    @track sortBy;
    @track sortDirection;   
    @track opportunities;
    error;
    @track cols=Columns;
    wiredOpp;
    rowLimit =20;
    rowOffSet =0;
    baseData;
    @wire(getopportunities, {val: '$recordId'}, {limitSize: this.rowLimit}, {offset: this.rowOffSet})
    wiredOpp({error, data}){
        if(data){
           this.opportunities = data.map((row) => {
            return this.mapOpp(row);
           })
        this.baseData = this.opportunities
        }
        else if(error){
            this.error = error;
            this.opportunities = undefined;
        }
        console.log(data);
        console.log(error);
    }

    mapOpp(row){
        console.log(row);
        var UserName = '';
        var Userlink = '';
        if (row.End_User__r.Id != undefined){
            UserName = `${row.End_User__r.Name}`
            Userlink = `/${row.End_User__r.Id}`
        }
        return{...row,
           Amount: `${row.Amount}`,
           StageName: `${row.StageName}`,
           Name: `${row.Name}`,
           link: `/${row.Id}`,
           End_User__c: UserName,
           End_User_link: Userlink,
           Account_Name: `${row.Account.Name}`,
           accountlink: `/${row.AccountId}` 


        };
    }

    handleSortAccountData(event) {       
        this.sortBy = event.detail.fieldName;       
        this.sortDirection = event.detail.sortDirection;       
        this.sortAccountData(event.detail.fieldName, event.detail.sortDirection);
    }


    sortAccountData(fieldname, direction) {
        
        let parseData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.opportunities));
       
        let keyValue = (a) => {
            return a[fieldname];
        };


       let isReverse = direction === 'asc' ? 1: -1;


           parseData.sort((x, y) => {
            x = keyValue(x) ? keyValue(x) : ''; 
            y = keyValue(y) ? keyValue(y) : '';
           
            return isReverse * ((x > y) - (y > x));
        });
        
        this.opportunities = parseData;


     
     }
     handleSearch(event){
        var searchTerm = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
        this.opportunities = this.baseData.filter((row) => {
            for (let field of Object.values(row)) {
                if (field && field.toString().toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        });
    }}
```

[image: The white box I want to remove]

[image: The subtitle I want to add]

Comment: Could you provide more clarity on what your problem is? You mention a white box, but it is confusing. Thanks.

Comment: Yes sorry, I am trying to remove the white rectangle I highlighted in red so that the background is only grey with the title. I think it is displaying like this because of the lightning card. What is the best way to display the title to avoid the white rectangle being displayed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always check the underlying HTML of a component like "lightning-card" (using inspect in your browser) and try to mimic it using the classes they have. For example, try replacing the **lightning-card tags** (and their content) with the following snippet of code (made of HTML using classes taken from the Lightning Design System https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/cards/):

```
    <div class="slds-card__header slds-grid slds-media slds-media_center slds-has-flexi-truncate">
        <div class="slds-media__figure"><lightning-icon size="small" icon-name="standard:opportunity" alternative-text="Approved" title="Approved"></lightning-icon></div>
        <h2 class="slds-card__header-title">Opportunity</h2>
    </div>
```

You should get something like this (it inherits the parent tag background).

[image]

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help It works really well!

Comment: Happy to help! Please, do not forget to select this as the correct answer if it corrected your issue! @Pierre-OlivierThibault